# User defined functions is not working in better-sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, user-defined-functions, better-sqlite3

I have a `node.js` server that connects and initializes a `sqlite` database. I am using the `better-sqlite3` library.

But the server never gets started. It gives below error:

[image]

Tables schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (

    user_id       text        NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() ,
    email         text UNIQUE NOT NULL                           ,
    full_name     text        NOT NULL                           ,
    profile_photo text                 DEFAULT ''                ,    
    passhash      text        NOT NULL                           ,
    created_time  int         NOT NULL DEFAULT now()             ,
    settings      text        NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'              ,       

    CHECK ( length ( user_id ) = 36 ) ,
    CHECK ( length ( email     ) >= 3  AND length ( email     ) <= 100 ) ,
    CHECK ( length ( full_name ) >= 1  AND length ( full_name ) <= 100 ) ,
    CHECK ( length ( passhash  ) >= 8  AND length ( passhash  ) <= 100 ) ,
    CHECK ( length ( profile_photo  ) >= 0  AND length ( profile_photo  ) <= 1000 ) , 

    PRIMARY KEY ( user_id )

) STRICT;
```

Part of `node.js` server code:

```
function setup (config) {
    db = new Database('colube.db', { verbose: console.log }); 
    db.pragma('journal_mode = WAL');

    if (!isTablesCreated(db)) {
        addFns(db);

        let path      = getPath('db/migrations/V0001__sqlite3_initial_version.sql');
        let migration = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');

        db.exec(migration);
    }
}
```

My `user-defined functions`:

```
function addFns (db) {

    db.function('gen_random_uuid', () => {
        return v4();
    }); 
    
    db.function('now', () => {
        return Date.now();
    }); 
}
```

The error is thrown when executing `sqlite` migration file . Migration works fine when removing the use of `gen_random_uuid` and `now`(user-defined functions).

Since the document of `better-sqlite3` states clear that it supports `user-defined functions`, I don't know how to solve this problem.

[better-sqlite3 document: user defined function](https://github.com/WiseLibs/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/api.md#functionname-options-function---this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from `better-sqlite3` community on github that solved my problem, the link of the reply: [Help: syntax error](https://github.com/WiseLibs/better-sqlite3/issues/821). Below is the content of the reply:

The problem is that you're using invalid syntax. The correct syntax is described as:

> An explicit DEFAULT clause may specify that the default value is NULL, a string constant, a blob constant, a signed-number, or any constant expression enclosed in parentheses. A default value may also be one of the special case-independent keywords CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

In other words, you must enclose gen_random_uuid() in parenthesis, like (gen_random_uuid()). The same must be done for now() -> (now()).